# Typical raw sensor data?

Tags: ros, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It might be a silly question, but I would like to know for the sake of curiosity. I would like to see real sensor data for 2D case. I can't afford the cost of Laser sensors so far, but I'm sure that there is some recorded real data that allows me to understand and interpret this data. I know that data that is acquired by robot is represented in the robot's frame. For 2D, I should get the range and bearing to an obstacle. I've simulated the procedure in Matlab, but now I want see the real data. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/125466/typical-raw-sensor-data?/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2014-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to find a number of bagfiles floating around with recorded laser + odometry. A few examples:

- I have posted a number of such bagfiles (mostly from lower-cost lasers like the Neato XV-11 and Hokuyo URG): http://fergy.me/slam
- MIT has also posted bagfiles acquired on a PR2: http://projects.csail.mit.edu/stata/downloads.php These include a lot more than just laser data, so they are probably quite large.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2014-05-17**:
@fergs, thank you so much.